# Using OTHER_LDFLAGS with command line, iOS app generation command line

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am creating a tool to generate iOS app through command line using cordova. Everything was working fine but then i added Admob plugin and got a bunch of errors. But fortunately i got to know that i will have to add a few additional frameworks using xcode.

How can i provide additional frameworks usnig OTHER_LDFLAGS as we do $(inherited) in xcode

Please help anyone to get me out of this problem.

Comment: Did you find out anything about this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Yes i have fixed it, everything is working fine now. Big thanks

Comment: Then might be good if you posted the solution here, or closed the question.